# Why would I not be able to access VPS via FTP all of a sudden?

Tags: ftp, vps

I have a VPS, CentOS, was set up automatically with HyperVM.

I set up the FTP connection with lxadmin.

I've been logging into my server via FTP for weeks.

Today it says:

```
Status: Connecting to 74.126.30.21:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Delaying connection due to previously failed connection attempt...
Status: Connecting to 74.126.30.21:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I can still log in via SSH.

- what kinds of things could have caused this?
- what are some things I can check/change so I can use FTP again?

Here's my **netstat** output, how can I tell from this if the "**port is listening on the server itself**"?

[image]

it doesn't allow me to **telnet** to the listed ftp port:

[image]

here's the **iptables** info:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple Guesses:

1) You made some iptables rules changes to allow the traffic but did not commit them with 'service iptables save'

2) Is the FTP service running?

Does netstat show that the port is listening on the server itself?  If so, can you telnet to the port on the server itself, what about remotely?

Comment: how do I tell if the FTP service is running, with my current limited knowledge of linux admin I go to "cd /etc" look around, find nothing...

Comment: I didn't change anything since yesterday, SSH on port 22 still works, the website still works, just FTP refuses to connect, could this be a problem with my hosting provider, e.g. the virtual machine on which my vps is running?

Comment: I posted my netstat above.

Comment: output of 'iptables -L' ?

Comment: I posted the iptables info, what does that tell me?

Comment: Are you using active or passive FTP on your client?  I'm willing to bet that you had been using passive and somehow it got switched to active and now you can't transfer data.

Comment: iptables is not blocking the connections is what that told you.

Answer (score 1):

To show listening ports in netstat, use `-l`, e.g. `netstat -tlnp`. You can also use `lsof -i tcp:21`. To look for a running process use ps, e.g. `ps -ef | grep ftpd`.